# Will there be any effect if I change the varchar2 column size?

Tags: oracle, plsql, bigdata, oracle19c

I have a table with almost 20 columns and **at least one billion** rows.

What if I change type of one column from `varchar2(8)` to `varchar2(16)`? There is no index, constraint or foreign key on given column. But my table has too many records. I will use below script for the operation:

```
ALTER TABLE user MODIFY type VARCHAR2(16);
```

I have done this operation in my test environment but it does not have as many records as my production environment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I can tell, it'll be *instantly*. It is a `varchar2` column and change is being done only in data dictionary, table data isn't affected at all.

If it were `char`, then yes - it would take time because such a column contains data right-padded with spaces up to its full length, so you'd actually have to enlarge the column, but also perform update on a table, and that would take time if there are that many rows.

Comment: While this command can be used with no immediate impact, be aware that if your columns/rows are full, any updates that increase the row length *may* cause row chaining.